# Packaging web software for different linux distros

Tags: linux, apache, centos, debian-based

I'm trying to get some software working on Centos 7 that has been developed on Debian.

I've taught myself spec files and worked some edge cases - it's not perfect yet, but we are getting there.

The current hurdle is that the devs have hard coded the www-data user into the software.

In DEB systems: the apache web server is referred to as apache2 and the user is www-data.

In RPM systems: the apache web server is called httpd and the user is apache.

It may well be different for other distros (Gentoo, Arch etc)

What is the recommended method for making this code generic for any linux distro, so that the apache2/httpd user is correct?

Comment: So you create a diff config per distro?

Comment: Or you use a tool such as sed during the build process to substitute the correct value in.